# Функция "move_and_slide" возвращает значение, но это значение никогда не используется

Tags: godot, gdscript

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var speed  = 100
var jump = 300
var gravitation = 400
var vel = Vector2()
func _phisics_process(_delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
        vel.x -= speed
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
        vel.x += speed
    else:vel.x = 0
    move_and_slide(vel, Vector2.UP)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо использовать возвращаемое значение функции "move_and_slide" для присвоения его переменной. Например:

```
var slide_vel = move_and_slide(vel, Vector2.UP)
vel = slide_vel
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: @Олег примите ответ (серая галочка слева)